# Problem making an autorun file to open cd content plus an application

Tags: windows-xp, cd, autorun

I want to create a CD which contains many files [audio files, text files, applications, etc..], when the CD will be inserted it will open an application which shows a welcome screen to user and guides him, plus it will also open the CD in explorer (simply show the contents of the CD allowing the user to select which files he wish to open).

The users are elders in a retirement home, we are teaching them how to use computers. 
The operation system is windows xp with autorun set on default.

my question is is it possible, and if so how?

And if not, is it possible to make the autorun load the application which will guide the user, but when the user accesses the drive itself via double-clicking it will open the cd contents.

Any help appreciated, thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it will be used in Windows only, try this: create two files (`autorun.inf` and `open.bat`) in the root directory of your CD.

Put this inside `autorun.inf`

```
[autorun]
ShellExecute=open.bat
```

...and this inside `open.bat`

```
start <path to the dir you want to open>
start <path to the default cd app>
```